# Unable to install Eclipse for Java EE

Tags: java, eclipse, installation

I'm not able to install Eclipse for Java EE on my working machine. Eclipse for Java is already installed. 
I get with the installer also with the advanced mode, an error in the installation. I assume that this is due to some limitations of my working machine. Admin rights are used. Do you have any idea?
Thank you!

Comment: Eclipse requires a separate IDE for Java EE?

Comment: @AlonsodelArte Eclipse comes in many difference [packages](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/), depending on what it is you want to use it for. You can start with the plain vanilla package and add modules to get the features you need, or pick a pre-built package with most/all the features you need.

Comment: Hi, please share information about the error either a screenshot or a log trace should be enough.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague to give a proper answer. It quite helpful to know what kind of error your are having,Even a screen shot would be helpful to give you a better answer. Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to have better answers. Good luck